# Preselect a default page in iron-pages when using with paper-tabs

Tags: javascript, polymer, polymer-1.0

I am using Polymer `iron-pages` along with `paper-tabs` in my rails app. The problem is none of pages were shown until one of the `paper-tabs` was clicked. I want the first page in `iron-pages` to be selected by default without user interaction.

I have put both `paper-tabs` and `iron-pages` in a `<template is='dom-bind'></template>`. Have read documentation about data binding, But I couldn't figure out how to achieve this. Please somebody suggest your valuable suggestions. Thank you.

```
<template is="dom-bind">
  <div class="middle">
    <paper-tabs class="bottom self-end" selected="{{selected}}">
      <paper-tab>Page 1</paper-tab>
      <paper-tab>Page 2</paper-tab>
    </paper-tabs>
  </div>
  <div class="bottom">
    <iron-pages selected="{{selected}}">
      <div> Page 1(This should be selected by default.)
      </div>
      <div> Page 2
      </div>
    </iron-pages>
  </div>
</template>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since you're working with an auto-binding template, simply add a short script that sets the `selected` property of your `<iron-pages>` element at load time. For example (assuming you are using `webcomponents-lite.js`):

```html
<template is="dom-bind">
  <div class="middle">
    <paper-tabs class="bottom self-end" selected="{{selected}}">
      <paper-tab>Page 1</paper-tab>
      <paper-tab>Page 2</paper-tab>
    </paper-tabs>
  </div>
  <div class="bottom">
    <iron-pages selected="{{selected}}">
      <div> Page 1 (This will be selected by default.)
      </div>
      <div> Page 2
      </div>
    </iron-pages>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  document.addEventListener('WebComponentsReady', function () {
    var template = document.querySelector('template[is="dom-bind"]');
    template.selected = 0; // selected is an index by default
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 7):

If you are using Polymer you can also set the default view by defining it in the Polymer properties of your web component:

```
Polymer({
  is: 'your-web-component',

  properties: {
    selected: {
        value: 0
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the custom element's constructor() to set the property to name of the tab that should be selected

```
<paper-tabs id="choiceTab" style="width:400px;" attr-for-selected='name' selected="{{choice}}">
                    <paper-tab name="tab1">Tab 1</paper-tab>
                    <paper-tab name="tab2">Tab 2</paper-tab>

                </paper-tabs>
```

.....

```
static get properties() {
            return {
                choice: {
                    type: String,
                    reflectToAttribute: true
                }
            };
        }
```

.....

```
constructor() {
                super();
                this.choice = 'tab1';
            }
```